# Communication between activity and (bound) service handlers using a local binder

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-service, android-handler, messenger

Somehow I find this confusing:

If your activities and bound service run in the same process, and you want to communicate asynchronously between activity and bound service (which is set to the foreground using a notification), how do you use handlers on both sides? The part that I don't understand is that both the activity-side and service-side run in the same thread: the UI-thread. That means THE SAME HANDLER!

I used to program it like this: In my bound service I create a Handler, put that handler into a Messenger, return the Messenger in the onBind() method. On the activity-side I create a ServiceConnection object with onServiceConnected() and onServiceDisconnected(). I also create a client Handler and put that in a client Messenger object. I also define a service Messenger object which gets its Messenger object handed out in the onServiceConnected() method of the ServiceConnection object. Everything is setup now.

I believe I could remove the whole Messenger part between the activity and service and only use a local binder object (because the activity and the service run on the same ui-thread). That way you only have ONE thread for both sides and two handlers and two Messengers. Why have two handlers/messengers in the same thread? Is that the ONLY way to get asynchronous communication? I don't want to call methods in the service directly from the activity (as you normally would do using a local Binder object), because that is synchronous communication!